# pointer addresses in c struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct try {
    int x,*x_Ptr;
    float y,*y_Ptr;
    char q,*q_Ptr;
};  //integer, float character variables and their pointers are defined in the structures.
int main (void){

    struct try den1;
    struct try den2;
    struct try den3;

    den1.x=7;
    den2.x=8;
    den1.y=-.14;
    den2.y=23.45;
    den3.q='A';

    den1.x_Ptr=&den1.x; //pointer assignments for integer.
    den2.x_Ptr=&den2.x;

    den1.y_Ptr=&den1.y; //pointer assignments for float.
    den2.y_Ptr=&den2.y;

    den3.q_Ptr=&den3.q; //pointer assignments for character.
    system("clear");


    printf("The integer in den1:%d\nThe integer in den2:%d\nThe address of integer in den1:%p\nThe address of integer in den2:%p\nThe pointer address of integer in den1:%p\nThe pointer address of integer in den2:%p\n",den1.x,den2.x,&den1.x,&den2.x,&*den1.x_Ptr,&*den2.x_Ptr);

    printf("\n");
    printf("The float in den1:%f\nThe float in den2:%f\nThe address of float in den1:%p\nThe address of float in den2:%p\nThe pointer address of float in den1:%p\nThe pointer address of float in den2:%p\n",den1.y,den2.y,&den1.y,&den2.y,&*den1.y_Ptr,&*den2.y_Ptr);

    printf("\n");
    printf("The character in den3:%c\nThe address of character in den3:%p\nThe pointer address of character in den3:%p\n",den3.q,&den3.q,&*den3.q_Ptr);

    printf("\n");

    printf("\nThe whole address of the first struct{...\n...\n...\n...\t\t\t}den1:%p\n",&den1);
    printf("\nThe whole address of the second struct{...\n...\n...\n...\t\t\t}den2:%p\n",&den2);
    printf("\nThe whole address of the second struct{...\n...\n...\n...\t\t\t}den3:%p\n",&den3);

    return 0;
}
```

I realized that address of one of the integer in the struct and address of struct are the same. What is the reason?

Comment: [c11 6.7.2.1p15](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) "Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning."

Comment: @IanAbbott That could be an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that address of one of the integer in the struct and address of struct are the same. What is the reason?

Because they have the same address.

The struct takes up the combined space of all of its members. The address of an object is the address of its first byte. den1.x is the first member of den1, so it starts at the same byte at den1 starts at.

A picture is worth a thousand words:

```
address   data
00123458  07     \ <- address of x                 \  <- address of den1
00123459  00     |                                  |
0012345a  00     | space used by x                  |
0012345b  00     /                                  | space
0012345c  58   \ <- address of x_ptr                | used
0012345d  34   |                                    | by
0012345e  12   | space used by x_ptr                | den1
0012345f  00   /                                    |
00123460  29     \ <- address of y                  |
00123461  5c     |                                  |
00123462  0f     | space used by y                  |
00123463  be     /                                  |
00123464  60   \ <- address of y_ptr                |
00123465  34   |                                    |
00123466  12   | space used by y_ptr                |
00123467  00   /                                    |
00123468  41     } address of c                     |
00123469  00   \  (c only takes 1 byte)             |
0012346a  00   | padding so that c_ptr starts       |
0012346b  00   / on a multiple of 4 bytes           |
0012346c  68     \ <- address of c_ptr              |
0012346d  34     |                                  |
0012346e  12     | space used by c_ptr              |
0012346f  00     /                                  /
```